# Azure Stream Analytics - Outputting input if blob reference not found

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have an azure stream analytics receiving input from event hub. I then enrich the messages with a blob reference using a left join.
If the join fails, the enrichment fields end up as null as I was expecting, but if the blob does not exist at all, the stream analytics does not even output anything, no errors is thrown and the job continues running (it does not fail and stop).

Any idea on how I can achieve this? Since I see no error I was expecting to have the same results as a miss join.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this. This is actually the expected behavior when there is no reference data: if the blob doesn't exist in the specified path, the Stream Analytics job will wait for the blob to become available. 
You can detect this issue since a warning will be generated in activity logs.

We updated the doc with this information. Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)